# Can the load rating of a tyre change if rim size changes?

Tags: wheels

I have a 2014 Honda CRV and I'm trying to find new tyres for it.

The placard says 225 / 65 / 17R 102T but looking at the current tyres they are actually 225 /60 / 18R 100H.

The rims seemed to have been upgraded to be 18 inch rims but I don't understand why the loading rating on my old tyres is only 100. Do bigger rims change the load rating as well? Did the dealership install the wrong tyres?

I'm just wondering now when I find my new tyres whether I need the load rating to be 100 or 102?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, it's possible that 102 is not available in the R18 size. The difference in the load rating is only 90lbs (or 50kg), so not a huge amount in the scope 1700+ lbs (800+ kg).

As far as *"why"*, I'd say it's likely because of the change in the sidewall and overall geometry not supporting the same ratings without a major redesign of the tire materials and structure.

Note: this answer is all somewhat speculative, but based on the best information I could get. I did find a reference of R18 w/ a rating of 102T, however that was for a 2012 Ford, not a CRV, so Honda may refuse to use it, and it wasn't something I could buy, just a datasheet mention of the tire.

[Load Index Table](https://info.kaltire.com/load-index/)

Comment: The load rating of the tire is rather specific to the construction of the tire as well as its characteristics. It's possible for bigger diameter tires to have higher load ratings as well as lower load ratings - even if it's the same product. From what I've seen, there's no real rhyme or reason for it.

Comment: @Kitsunemimi they do go both directions on the ratings. My point is if there is not much reason for a specific tire the companies won't bother designing and producing it. Most of the R18 tires I found that did have a 102 load rating were wider (235 rather than 225). So likely that's the more commonly needed tire, so they make it. If 228/R18/102 is exceedingly rare they may not make it at all anymore. I just knkw that I couldn't find any.